# How to filter only unique pairs in permutations, python?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

```
from itertools import permutations
list0 = [1, 2, 3]
for el1, el2 in permutations(list0, r=2):
    print(el1, el2)
```

Output:

```
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3
3 1
3 2
```

This output contains all possible permutations, I need unique combinations of numbers, how should I filter them, maybe I should use another code. I need

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Comment: Use `itertools.combinations` instead of `itertools.permutations`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combinations` instead of `permutations` to achieve that

```
from itertools import combinations
list0 = [1, 2, 3]
for combination in combinations(list0, 2):
    print(combination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you probably looking for [combinations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/itertools-combinations-module-python-print-possible-combinations/)